# Filtering Dataset with AWK based on list

Tags: text-processing, awk, variable

I want to get rows filtered from dataframe based on the condition if they are present in the list. So far I have tried this thing.But I am getting unexpected result. The data is getting replicated and Iam unable to understand it

```
#!/bin/bash
arr_country=(AL AD AM AT BY BE BA BG CH)
for element in "${arr_country[@]}"
do
awk -F '\t' '{if($1==$element){print}}'   abc.txt >>xyz.txt
done
echo
echo "Data Transferred"
```

The sample dataset contains information about diferent countries with first column representing the country name. I want to subset the dataset based on the array given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element` is not an `awk` variable.

To import the value of a shell variable into an `awk` script, you may use

```
awk -v variable="$value" '{ script goes here }'
```

In the example above, the variable called `variable` would get the value of the shell variable called `value`.  You would use `variable` in the `awk` script without prefixing it with `$`.

Note that if you prefix a variable with `$` in `awk`, it assumed that the variable's value is a positive integer and that it refers to a specific field in the current input record.  The expression `$element` would, for example, give you the value of field number `element` (just like `$1` gives you the value of first field and `$NF` gives you the value of the last field, where `NF` is the built in variable denoting the number of fields in the current record).

If `element` is unset in the `awk` code, `$element` would therefore be expanded to `$0` which is the complete line.  Your code would then print the whole line if its first tab-delimited field was the only thing on the line.

Your `awk` script could also be shortened to

```
awk -F '\t' -v e="$element" '$1 == e'
```

Or, you could replace the whole thing with

```
arr_country=(AL AD AM AT BY BE BA BG CH)

( IFS='|'; grep -E "^(${arr_country[*]})\>" ) <abc.txt >xyz.txt
```

or,

```
grep -E '^(AL|AD|AM|AT|BY|BE|BA|BG|CH)\>' <abc.txt >xyz.txt
```

The `${arr_country[*]}` parameter substitution will expand to a single string consisting of your array's values delimited by the first character of `$IFS`.  This creates a regular expression identical to the second `grep` shown above.  `\>` will match the zero-width space at the end of a word (so that `^AA\>` matches `AA` at the start of a line but not `AAA`).

The only difference is that the result may be differently ordered compared to the shell loop solution with `awk`.

---

A different approach to eliminating the shell loop (assuming the default value of `$IFS`):

```
arr_country=(AL AD AM AT BY BE BA BG CH)

awk -v c="${arr_country[*]}" -F '\t' '
    BEGIN { n=split(c,a," "); for (i=1;i<=n;++i) country[a[i]] }
    $1 in country' <abc.txt >xyz.txt
```

Here, we give the elements of `arr_country` as a space-delimited string to the `awk` code in the variable `c`.  Before starting to read from the input, the `c` string is split into pieces and each piece is made into a key in an associative array `country`.  If the first field is a key in that array, the line is printed.